# Create object from View input and pass it to ViewModel (in MVVM)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

Recently I'm developing my first project using **[MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)** concept (I use **[WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)**). I've read many tutorials (ia. famous [J.Smith's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) one) about **MVVM** before I started writing a code. Everything I've read had been clear until I started to code...

The problem is simple: in *View* layer I have a form with `TextBox`es. Let's say a few `TextBox`es, ie.: **Name**, **Surname**, **Phone number**. When user fills all of them and clicks **OK**-button, I want to add new person (with specified personal details) to my local **Database** (I use *Entity Framework* as a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)).

To do this I need to write something like this:

```xml
<Button Name="MyButton" Command="MyRelayCommandWhichNeedsAllOfTheTextboxes" Content="OK" />
```

Using `CommandParameter` I can pass one object from *View* to *ViewModel*. There are many textboxes so it's probably not a good idea.

From *XAML* I can assign to `CommandParameter` whole form which needs to be filled by user. But then, inside *ViewModel*, I need to know all textboxes' names. The main assumption in MVVM is that all the layers (View, ViewModel and Model) have to be independent.

What's the best solution? How can I pass input data from form to *ViewModel*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having the relay command as part of your View Model -- that way, when the command gets triggered, you'll have access to all the properties you need.

**XAML:**

```
<Button Name="SurnameTextBox" Text="{Binding Surname,Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding MyRelayCommand}" Content="OK" />
```

**View Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // (note, raise property changed on the setter
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICommand MyRelayCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel
    {
        // set the command callback here
        MyRelayCommand = new RelayCommand(OKCommandHandler); 
    }

    private void OKCommandHandler(object parameter)
    {
        // save the record here using Surname, etc
        // (note that you don't even need to use parameter, so you can just ignore it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to pass data from form to viewmodel because your viewmodel has allready all data.

your viewmodel expose all data through properties to your view and you bind to it. look at dbaseman answer.